# Protractor returns success even when expect fails

Tags: javascript, protractor, cucumber, chai

I am new with protractor and I am traying to mount a project with it and cucumber.

The scenario goes as below

```
  Scenario: User login
    Given the page is open
    And email is set with value n@n.com
    And password is set with value 123
    When the user click on login button
    Then home page is displayed
```

The steps definition are implemented and the login_page.js is as below

```
var chai = require('chai').use(require('chai-as-promised'));
var expect = chai.expect;

var LoginPage = function() {

    this.get = function() {
        browser.get('https://aaa/login');
    };

    this.setEmail = function(value) {
        element(by.id('login-email')).sendKeys(value);
    };

    this.setPassword = function(value) {
        element(by.id('login-password')).sendKeys(value);
    };

    this.clickAccede = function() {
        element(by.id('login-submit')).click()
    };

    this.pageIsLoaded = function() {
        browser.waitForAngular();
        expect(browser.getTitle()).to.be.eventually.equals('page title');
    };
};
```

Then when I run the scenario I am receiving the result below

```
  Scenario: User login
  ✔ Given the page is open
  ✔ And email is set with value n@n.com
  ✔ And password is set with value 123
  ✔ When the user click on login button
  ✔ Then home page is displayed

1 scenario (1 passed)
5 steps (5 passed)
0m00.005s
[16:23:50] E/launcher - expected 'aaa' to equal 'page title'
[16:23:50] E/launcher - AssertionError: expected 'aaa' to equal 'page title'
[16:23:50] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

As you can see the assertion is failing but the result return success.
What am I missing?

Comment: Don't use `expect` in page objects https://www.protractortest.org/#/style-guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    this.Then(/^shipment page is displayed$/, function () { return expect(browser.getTitle().then((value)=>{
console.log(value);return value;
})).to.be.eventually.equals('page title'); });
```

Use this and check

Comment: Welcome buddy enjoy

Answer (score 0):

@Bharath
My step definition

```
this.Then(/^shipment page is displayed$/, function (callback) {
    expect(browser.getTitle()).to.be.eventually.equals('page title');
    callback();
});
```

Comment: this.Then(/^shipment page is displayed$/, function (callback) { expect(browser.getTitle()).to.be.eventually.equals('page title'); callback(); });